# Start up order for Oracle Forms

Tags: oracleforms

I have to modify an Oracle Form but cannot find my way to start.

What is the start up order for a standard form?  That is which event, trigger etc will be called at form load, canvas load, etc.  I assume that it is When-New-form-Instance but a cannot get it to stop at a break point on the first line of this trigger.

I am getting

> FRM-40735 ON_ERROR trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06508

Which I suspect means I do not have my environment set up correctly but I have done the same as others at this site.  So I thought to start with debugging and try to identify which call is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRE-FORM` fires before `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE`. Check what's defined in `PRE-FORM` trigger.

Also, your `ON-ERROR` trigger is giving a ORA-06508 error, so might want to check what program unit is being referred to in the `ON-ERROR` trigger

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I know I need to work out why its generating an ORA-06508.  I suspect its the same root cause - not finding the attached libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To get a start in trying to find the source of the error, try disabling custom code in forms. If the error does not persist when custom code is disabled, you'll have to start tracing through CUSTOM.PLL to find the source of the issue.